# How to disable clipboard redirection for my users from their local systems in xrdp

Tags: 20.04, clipboard, xrdp

I am an administrator of the Ubuntu Server. I have 7 users. They log in through RDP. So I need to disable the clipboard from their local machine to the remote system. How to achieve this?

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, xRDP indeed will allow clipboard redirection and drive redirection.  If you edit the following file

> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

Scroll through the file and locate the section

> [Channels]

You will see something like this

```
[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true
```

Change value to false for the cliprdr (clibpoard redirection) and rdpdr (drive redirection).  So, your file should look like this

```
[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=false
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=false
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true
```

Then restart your xrdp service to use the new settings.

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya